# Internal URL with a Fragment ID

Tags: ipad, webview, fragment-identifier

I have a large `.htm` file in the main bundle I wish to load into a webview. No problem until I append a fragment id to the end of the URL. I want the webview to open at an anchor id `#c` on a button press.

BTW: If I create a URL http://www.mydomain.com/database.htm#c and load this from the Internet. All all is good.

I have tried several approaches. Both have failed. I am guessing the server side does the parsing of the URL on the internet, but the iPhone does not have that capability. Does anyone have a suggestion? Please be explicit with examples if possible. I am a noob and on my own.

Stumped

```
 NSString *path         = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"database1.htm" ofType:nil];
 NSString *pathWithFrag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%",path, @"#c"];
 NSURL *baseURL         = [ NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathWithFrag];
 [spinner2 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:baseURL]];
 [super viewDidLoad];
```

OR

```
 NSString *path  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"database1.htm" ofType:nil];
 NSURL *baseURL  = [ NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
 NSURL *newURL   = [baseURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"#c"];
 [spinner2 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:newURL]];
 [super viewDidLoad];
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it may an issue with NSURL url-escaping the "#" character: http://9mmedia.com/blog/?p=299

Following the method on that blog post, something like this might work:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"database1.htm" ofType:nil];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURL *fullURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"#c" relativeToURL:baseURL];
[spinner2 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fullURL]];
[super viewDidLoad];
```

Answer (score 0):

The extra `%` in the `pathWithFrag` format may be causing problems: try `@"%@%@"`, not `@"%@%@%"`

Comment: Sorry, That was an artifact from a previous attempt. The 2 %s don't work either. Menawhile I found that by using WebKit framework I can scroll to the portion of the htm that I want.
    DOMDocument *doc = [[spinner2 mainframe] DOMDocument];    
    DomElement *element = [doc getElementById:@"#c"];    
    [element scrollIntoView:YES];   I am working on how to get the declarations correctly formatted.     Thanks for your help.